# Let $M=A^{t}.A$ , then $M_{k} =0 $ iff $A_{k}=0$, where $M_{k}$ and $A_{k}$ are the k-th rows of M and A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $M=A^{t}.A$ where $A$ is a $d\times m$ matrix,  if the $k-th$ row of $M$ and $A$ are especificed by $M_{k}$ and $A_{k}$, respectively, then $M_{k} =0 $ iff $A_{k}=0$, i tried to compute by the simple definition of matrix products but for me this its not true, that is only true if $M=A.A^{t}$.

Comment: Presumably you mean matrices with entries in $\mathbb{R}$. If complex entries are allowed, the claim can fail.

Comment: Hint: Compute $M_{k,k}$, the diagonal element of the $k$-th row of $M$.